# Collection library for Ruby

Tags: ruby, data-structures

Is there something like collection classes from Guava for Ruby? So far I've only found implementation of red-black tree which is not in the same league as say Java TreeMap class.

Comment: Have a look at [`kanwei/algorithms`](https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms) gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms is the right answer. not widely advertised though. KL-7 has the same idea it seems.